# Convert From ASIhttpRequest To AFNetwork?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest, afnetworking

MY Code In ASIHTTPRequest Is :

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://avicenna-apps.com/harleyeventget.php"];
ASIHTTPRequest *_Request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
__weak ASIHTTPRequest * Request=_Request;
[Request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSData *Data = [Request responseData];
];
[Request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = [Request error];
      NSlog(@"Error IS %@,error");
}];
[Request startAsynchronous];
```

How Can I Write It In AFNetwork ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place for code request, we are here to help you but do expect some effort from you as wel. Just post code and asking how do you write this for `AFNetwork` is not a good question. Please try to solve the problem your self, write some code and then if you still did not succeed post you code here so we can help.

Comment: i try to write this code in AFNetwork But I Didnot understand parameters Required to get responseObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside `AFHttpClient`,

```
  (void)getPath:(NSString *)path
     parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
        success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
        failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
```

here is the official site for AFNetworking, [click](http://afnetworking.com)

Comment: @Tefa responseObject is not a parameter to be passed in. If your "harleyeventget.php" return something, the value would be in responseObject.  I think you need to get an objective-c book to read first.